# Hadoop - Saving Log Data and Developing GUI

Tags: java, python, hadoop

I am doing research for my new project, Following is the details of my project, research and questions:

Project:

1. Save the Logs (ex. format is TimeStamp,LOG Entry,Location,Remarks etc ) from different sources. Here Different sources is like, gettting the LOG data from the different systems world wide (Just an Overview)
2. (After saving the LOG Entries in Hadoop as specified in 1) Generate Reports of the LOGs saved in Hadoop on demand like drill down, drill up etc

NOTE: For every minute approx. thier will be 50 to 60 MB of LOG Entries from the systems (I checked it).

Research and Questions:

1. For saving log entries in the Hadoop from different sources, we used Apache Flume.
2. We are creating our own MR programs and servlets.

Is thier any good options other than flume?
Is thier any Hadoop Data Analysis (Open Source) tool to genarte reports etc?

I am doing my research, if any of us add some comments to me it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Datameer ? It provides a GUI to import all these types of files, and create reports as well as dashboards.

Comment: Yes, but, it is not open source. Also, we need Open source so that we can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use HIVE. Even I am new to Hadoop but read some where that HIVE is for hadoop analytics. Not sure whether it has GUI or not, but for sure it has SQL capability to query unstructed data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. we are using PIG. HIve or PIG does not have GUI.